# Killing a job in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu

This is probably a frequently asked question, but I've been unable to find good documentation.

I have jobs running on my system:

```
foo@fooBox:~/tmp$ jobs
[1]+  Stopped                 foo bar baz
```

How can I kill this process? I've tried various commands, like `kill 1`, but it hasn't worked.

Comment: alternatively, $fg [enter] [ctrl-c] :p

Comment: @bubu: That won't work for some programs that catch `SIGINT`, such as `vim`.

Comment: @Mark Szymanski I knew, I knew :p

Answer (score 37):

You can use the method suggested by @fideli, or you can use the `kill` command like so:

```
kill %1
```

This will kill the first suspended command. You can also find a list of suspended commands like so:

```
jobs
```

and it will provide output like such:

```
[1]+  Stopped                 yes
```

If you have multiple stopped jobs, the number in brackets (`[1]`) will be the job number, the one you provide after the `%` in the `kill` command.

Comment: This is great! Learned something new about `kill`.

Comment: How come I get this `-bash: kill: (3593) - Operation not permitted`. When I use it with sudo, I get this `kill: %1: invalid process id`

Comment: @CMCDragonkai You've hit a situation where the command you've run is now owned by a different user because you used `sudo`, so you can't kill it, but running `kill` using `sudo` means you no longer have access to your user's job list (try running `sudo jobs` to see what I mean).  Instead, since you now have the PID, simply run `sudo kill 3593`.

Comment: How can a backgrounded process be owned by another user?

Answer (score 7):

If you run `ps ax` you will get a list of all processes running. Look for the one you want to kill and note the number in the `PID` column. E.g. say the number was `10203`, you would then run:

```
kill 10203
```

You can also run `ps ax | grep foo` to find the exact program you're looking for. Finally, you could run:

```
killall foo
```

to kill all instances of `foo`.